# how to use setObject: forKey where Key is also a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` inside another `NSMutableDictionary` how should i set a value inside the inner `NSMutableDictionary`, I have tried

```
[[PUser setObject:self.name forKey:@"profile"][@"name"];
```

but it gives subscript requires size of interface'NSString',which is not consistent with this architecture and platform error,any suggestions?

Comment: The way to do it is to break it into individual lines that you can understand and debug -- fetch a pointer to the inner dictionary, then operate on that pointer on the next line.  (Your above line is missing a `]`, by the way.  Or perhaps more accurately, it has a `[` it doesn't need.)

Comment: (Don't use variable names starting with upper-case characters.  Reserve that for class names.)

Comment: (Did you try `[PUser[@"name"] setObject:self.name forKey:@"profile"];`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lets say your dictionary structure is like this :

```
mainDictionary = {
    "innerDictionary" = {
        "profile":"somename",
        "key2":"someValue",
        "key3":"someValue"
        }
}
```

**1) Now if you want to set value** of for key "`profile`" which is inside `innerDictionary` then you can set it as follows:

```
[mainDictionary setValue:yourValue forKeyPath:@"innerDictionary.profile"];
```

**2) if you want `object` to be saved** then do this:

```
[[mainDictionary valueForKey:@"innerDictionary"] setObject:yourValue forKey:@"profile"];
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code:

```
[[yourMainDic_Name objectForKey:@"innerDic_KeyName"] setValue:@"yourVlaue" forKey:@"KeyName"]; // you can also change as per your requirement to "setObject" instead of "setValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictmain,*dictsub; 

[dictmain setObject:dictsub forkey:@"dictsub"];
```

// This might be how a dictionary object added to another **dictionary**.

```
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = [dictmain objectforKey:@"dictsub"];
[innerdict setObject:customObj forKey@"new key"];
```

// This will insert a new object to the inner dictionary. Also you can use **setValue** method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add New key to Existing Key then First use `objectForKey:@"FirstKey"`
and
Then set New Value and NewKey what you want.

```
[[Dic objectForKey:@"name"] setObjcet:self.name  forKey:@"profile"];
```